# Whole Domain getting marked as malicious due to some bad files uploaded on mock/file hosting service

Tags: hosting, vpn, saas, mockserver

We offer a cloud based mock/file server as a service for debugging frontend apps. All the mocks get a url something like this

- username.xyz.com/endpoint
- xyz.com/endpoint?username=123

Due to some bad actors uploading some fishy files, our domain (xyz.com) is now detected as malicious by lots of websites/VPNs and end up getting blocked. This makes mocks unusable for them. Primarily it was reported on [abuse.sh](https://urlhaus.abuse.ch/browse/) but we took down the malicious files and user instantly and now the status shows as offline on `abuse.sh`.

Questions

1. What to do now to get our domain out of the malicious list from other websites/VPNs? Does improving domain authority help here?
2. What can we do here so that our whole domain doesn't take the hit for some users (subdomain) uploading some malicious files? Can only `username.xyz.com` be added to the abuse list?